# Add custom field in shipping address form of Checkout for Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento2

Below I have a shipping address form of checkout page and I would like to add another field(P.O. Box) in this form. I tried to look it up every forums and most of the answers were based on overriding `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor`. I checked `app/code/company/Checkout/etc/di.xml` but wasn't referencing `layoutprocessor`.

I am still confused from where this form is getting values from `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface` or `Magento\Checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml`

[image]

how can I add custom field to this form? Can anyone give me any suggestions? It would be really helpful appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

you should check `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface` to add a new field to the address.

Answer (score 0):

So after referring to lot of blogs I believe there are only 2 ways of creating custom field in which could be either by extending `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface` or by extending `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor` with the plugin created in  `app/code/vendor/Checkout/etc/di.xml`. Also I noticed that the only purpose of `Magento\Checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml` was to load the whole chunk in a single block rendering in one page as it could be used for adding validation.